# Plotting a function of x over a range of D

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot this function in MATLAB:

```
f(x) = (1./(2*b))*((erf(1./(2*D)+((x/b)-2*n)/D)+ erf(1./(2*D)-((x/b)-2*n)/D)));
```

The function is to plotted as a sum of `n` values from `0` to `N`, where `N` is a real number and `b` is a constant; for a range of `D` values. I am supposed to have different plots for each value in range `D` representing the function. How can I go about this please?

Comment: Trying to get the function to plot over different values of D. Also, there should be  a summation of the function from n=0 to a fixed value of N. I assume I am choosing the wrong ranges for D and do no t know how to sum the function from say n=0 to N=10. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different ranges of `D` can be done like this:

```
f = @(x, D)(x + D);

x = -10:10;  %// pick a good range
D = 1:5;     %// pick a good range

figure()
hold all

for d = D
    plot(x, f(x, d))
end
```

I'm not 100% sure what you mean about the summing 0:N bit but maybe it's something of this form:

```
figure()
hold all
x= -10:10;
for d = 1:5
  y = zeros(size(x));  %// Preallocation of memory for speed
  for n = 0:10  
    y = y + n*x + d
  end
  plot(x, y)
end
```

Comment: So, did you define the function as f(x) = x + D in your code?

Comment: And the d in your equation represents b? As for the summation for values of n = 0 to N; the summation sign is right in front of the error function parenthesis, summing values of n.

Comment: @user2108655 no the `d` is your `D`. I'm assuming your `b` is a constant. I'm looping over `d` so it's your `D`. I don't know what you mean about `n`, maybe type out your equation nicely in TeX or somthing?

Comment: yes **b** is a constant. However **D** depends on **b** as well. As for **n**, what I am trying to get is a summation of the entire function **f(x)** from values of **n** to **N**; like summation sign of a sequence. I'll try write the equation in TeX if that still does not help.

Comment: @user2108655 That's exactly what my second function example is doing

Comment: substituting my function definition seems to not work. Do I have to redefine the y in the second example?

Comment: @user2108655 it depends if you're summing your whole function or not, I think you;re not summing the terms without `n` so those must be in `n` loop and only added afterwards. Otherwise `y` is your function (well the term getting summed from 0:N)